# Overloading operator by using STL utility.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

In my code i have encountered 37 errors of the same type c2678; binary 'operator' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type 'type' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I am trying to remove the error by overloading the == operator, by including the STL "utility".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86s69hwc(v=vs.80).aspx
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading

But still this doesnt works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How including a header is supposed to overload operators for your type?

Comment: We need to at least see the code that is breaking.

Comment: @yurikilochek: See `<boost/operators.hpp>`.

Comment: @BoBTFish so? including this header doesn't magically provide overloads for your operators. You have to inherit from boost::operators<T>, and even then you have to provide basic ones so the others can be implemented in their terms.

Answer (score 1):

That header provides overloads of `operator==` for some standard types, but it won't magically overload it for your own types. If you want your types to be equality-comparable, then you'll have to overload the operator yourself, for example:

```
bool operator==(my_type const & a, my_type const & b) {
    return a.something == b.something
        && a.something_else == b.something_else;
}

// You'll probably want this as well
bool operator!=(my_type const & a, my_type const & b) {
    return !(a == b);
}
```